# Best way to update from Windows 10 Enterprise 1607 to 1903 offline

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, automatic-updates

We have a customer that our manufacture shipped some (4) PCs to a customer with a Windows Enterprise 1607 edition on them. The customer found a virus and want to run Windows update on these systems.

As I test, I ran Windows updates on the same OS. After about 3 hours it, was stuck on this download:

```
2019-04 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 version 1607 for x64-based Systems (KB4493470) at 95%.
```

I was accidentally cut the power to it, and after several reboots, it now seems to be successfully updated to Windows 10 1903.

Question: Is there a way I can do all the downloads offline, then just apply them? How would I identify exactly which files I need?

WSUS is not an option as this is a customer site and we have no control over how they do Windows updates.

I also that you can do it with an iso. I this possible, or would that wipe out the existing software?

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated. The hardest part is knowing if it's downloading or just stuck (as it apparently was this morning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select the options correctly when booting the ISO, it is entirely possible. It should be obvious when running the setup. Worth noting, you can start the installer from the ISO whilst the machine is running, just double click the ISO in explorer to mount it and then run the setup exe in the mounted ISO.

Although, this kind of thing does nothing to mitigate the impact of the virus, you should ensure you're absolutely positive that the system has been disinfected. Good luck!